# Validate the prices in `prod_price`. Remove any rows that are obviously wrong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried to work on the data frame. It is a big data and I have to remove inconsistent rows however when I try to check the inconsistency, the data is so big that i always get wrong answer.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from checker.binder import binder; binder.bind(globals())
from intro_data_analytics.check_scrubbing import *

df = pd.read_csv('data/inu_neko_orderline.csv')
df

trans_id    prod_upc    cust_id trans_timestamp trans_year  trans_month trans_day   trans_hour  trans_quantity  cust_age    cust_state  prod_price  prod_title  prod_category   prod_animal_type    prod_size   total_sales
0   10300097    719638485153    1001019 2021-01-01 07:35:21.439873  2021    1   1   1   1   20  NY  72.99   Cat Cave    bedding cat NaN 0
1   10300093    73201504044 1001015 2021-01-01 09:33:37.499660  2021    1   1   1   1   34  NY  18.95   Purrfect Puree  treat   cat NaN 0
2   10300093    719638485153    1001015 2021-01-01 09:33:37.499660  2021    1   1   1   1   34  NY  72.99   Cat Cave    bedding cat NaN 0
3   10300093    441530839394    1001015 2021-01-01 09:33:37.499660  2021    1   1   1   2   34  NY  28.45   Ball and String toy cat NaN 0
4   10300093    733426809698    1001015 2021-01-01 09:33:37.499660  2021    1   1   1   1   34  NY  18.95   Yum Fish-Dish   food    cat NaN 0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
38619   10327860    287663658863    1022098 2021-06-30 15:37:12.821020  2021    6   30  30  1   25  New York    9.95    All Veggie Yummies  treat   dog NaN 0
38620   10327960    140160459467    1022157 2021-06-30 15:45:09.872732  2021    6   30  30  2   31  Pennsylvania    48.95   Snoozer Essentails  bedding dog NaN 0
38621   10328009    425361189561    1022189 2021-06-30 15:57:44.295104  2021    6   30  30  2   53  New Jersey  15.99   Snack-em Fish   treat   cat NaN 0
38622   10328089    733426809698    1022236 2021-06-30 15:59:29.801593  2021    6   30  30  1   23  Tennessee   18.95   Yum Fish-Dish   food    cat NaN 0
38623   10328109    717036112695    1011924 2021-06-30 17:30:52.205912  2021    6   30  30  1   24  Pennsylvania    60.99   Reddy Beddy bedding dog medium  0
38624 rows × 17 columns
```

Comment: what is the logic here? I do not see anything **obvious**

Comment: post the consistency check code

Comment: we have no dieas what you want to do and what answer is wrong. Better show minial working code with example data and show wrong answer for this data and expected answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a row in the table which is a test row and the value of the price is too big (6 digits), while the maximum price is $72.
You need to delete this test row, then the data will be clean.

I found this row by downloading the coursera files and check it with google sheets

Answer (score 0):

I want to add answer for the one Jalal already said.

Although it is correct, but based on what I just tried today, if the number of total columns is wrong, they would still give error when you check it. Even after I filter out the data with no Float type, it's still wrong. So when I dropped all rows with NaN values, it was then they give me a pass.

Weird, I know.